# Elasticsearch filter multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following data set indexed in my elasticsearch

```
{
"title": "Professor",
"class": [6001, 6015, 6018],
"subject": [5010, 5012, 5013],
"salary": 12500
}

{
"title": "Professor",
"class": [6012, 6013, 6014],
"subject": [5010, 5005, 5004],
"salary": 16600
}

{
"title": "Principal",
"class": [7001, 7010, 6018],
"subject": [5010, 5012, 5013],
"salary": 14750
}

{
"title": "Asst Professor",
"class": [6012, 6013, 6014],
"subject": [5010, 5005, 5004],
"salary": 16600
}
```

I'm trying to search

*class  - 6001 OR 6018 OR 6013
AND
subject - 5013 OR 5004
AND
salary (range) - 12000 to 15000*

I'm using below query

```
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {            
                  "must" : [
                    { "term" : {"class" : [6001, 6018, 6013]}}, 
                    { "term" : {"subject" : [5013, 5004]}},
                    {"range" : {"salary" : {"gte": 12000,"lte": 15000}}}
                  ]
                }}}}}
```

But I'm not getting the result that Im expecting, what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **terms** filter instead of the **term** filter.

As per the docs:

> Term Filter: Filters documents that have fields that contain a term.
>
> Terms Filter: Filters documents that have fields that match any of the
> provided terms.

```
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {            
                  "must" : [
                    { "terms" : {"class" : [6001, 6018, 6013]}}, 
                    { "terms" : {"subject" : [5013, 5004]}},
                    { "range" : {"salary" : {"gte": 12000,"lte": 15000}}}
                  ]
                }}}}}
```

Comment: This works !! How to apply AND operator between terms?